# Tools for viewing AsyncStorage in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist, react-native-debugger

I want some tools to see async storage in android or IOS emulator. I need some tool to see that. I am currently using **React Native Debugger** in mac.
 
I want to see the content of async storage in each and every activity.What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

React Native Debugger has this built-in.

We can use `showAsyncStorageContentInDev()` in the RND console and we will be able to see the `asyncStorage`

But there is a problem with the integration of `asyncStorage` with debugger console. Some times it does not resolve anything. It happens while using react native with android.

Answer (score -1):

I think using `console.log()` is a good way to see it

Comment: I dont want to use console.log(). Its too frustrating to write in each and every screen.

Comment: Then I think you can use reactotron , it has Async Storage explorer
https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

Comment: Any other tool without using reactotron.?

Comment: Sorry I don`t know any other tools